# loop through checkboxes and get the values of rows with check

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

My table has two parts; the primary data and the sub part.
My objective is to copy the primary data into another sheet. And the subpart (which is in the same sheet of the primary) has to loop through row of choices with checkbox. Both primary and subpart will be copied into the last row of another sheet (together in single row) depends on the checkboxes with check only.

Comment: Further to @Cooper 's comment, I'm sorry but I don't understand your description of your spreadsheet, the "primary data" or the "subpart". Would you please edit your question to describe your scenario and provide examples of your data, and an example of the outcome your are trying to achieve. Regarding `loop through checkboxes and get the values of rows with check`, would you please describe your research for this prior to asking this question.

Comment: Hi Cooper and Tedinoz, thank you for noticing my problem posted here. However, while doing further research I already figured out the solution and managed to solve it yesterday. Sorry for the bother.